# Include questions that do not have accepted answers under the "unanswered" category?

Tags: feature-request

It would be useful to find out quickly which questions don't yet have accepted answers.  It seems that there typically are far more questions in that category than are without any kind of answer, so why not broaden what is meant by "unanswered"?

Answer (score 1):

You can search using [closed:0 hasaccepted:0](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted:0%20closed:0&submit=search), and that will return you all the questions without an accepted answer, which are not closed. If you want to see all your questions without an accepted answer, you can use [hasaccepted:0 closed:0 user:20519](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted:0%20closed:0%20user:20519&submit=search); instead of user:20519, you can use user:me, and it will be automatically changed in user:20519, when you enter "hasaccepted:0 closed:0 user:me" as search string, without you knowing your user ID.

[image: closed:0 hasaccepted:0]

If you look at https://english.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes, you get a list of question without up-voted answers, which is quite different.

[image: screenshot]

"Unanswered" in Stack Exchange always had a specific meaning: questions without up-voted answers. That practically included:

- Questions without an accepted answer
- Questions without up-voted answers
- Questions without answers

This is because for Stack Exchange accepting an answer is a type of vote. (The "VoteTypes" tables calls it "AcceptedByOriginator.")

Recently, the view that shown the unanswered questions has been split in two:

- votes, for questions without up-voted answers
- no answers, for questions without answers

I don't think those views will be rejoined again, as they were before.
Those views have been also limited as for the number of shown questions. I actually see 9 questions in the "votes" tab, and 5 questions in the "no answers" tab, which leads me to think 
those views filter the questions shown in the front page.

Comment: That display isn't really relevant. For example, as of right now, [this user](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/22539/nortonn-s) has asked 27 questions, and accepted **none**. But your link currently only shows eight "votes=0" questions (and only one of them is from the "non-acceptor" I flagged up). There must be hundreds if not thousands of questions with no accepted answer - there's no way to list them that I know of, and certainly your suggestion doesn't even come close.